# Golang http.Get block resources

Tags: go, filter, get, resources

How can I use Golang's net/http's `http.Get(url string)` but block certain url's and resources from request?

*E.g.*

```
http.Get("https://google.com") // But somehow block the main CSS file.
```

Comment: The http.Get function fetches one resource only.  In the case of `https://google.com/`, the CSS is inline on the page. It's not in a separate resource or file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to block URLs and resources because net/http `Get()` will not automatically perform fetching of included links or resources.

You probably confuse it with how a browser fetches a URL. A browser will issue a request and then follow up with fetching all the resources (Javascript/CSS/images/videos etc.) But Go's net/http request is much lower level - it is more like curl fetch - it will follow redirect by default, but otherwise it will just fetch a single response to the GET request.  You can think of the result of issuing a call `http.Get("https://google.com") as similar to what you see as in the browser as the page source (plus HTTP headers and response code). This response will likely to include a number of other URLs for links and resources - if you like, you can parse them out and request some or all of them (leaving out what you would want to "block"),  like low-level web crawlers do.